# How to subtract values based on another cell's value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, reference, subtraction

| keyword | value | keyword | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 6% | Apples | 2.21% |
| Apples | 5% | Mango | 8.40% |
| Mango | 2.10% | Orange | 9.50% |
| Orange | 3.40% | Apple | 3.10% |

I have an example sheet here. I need to first look for the row that contain the exact keyword values. Subtract Value 1 and Value 2 (Value 1 - Value 2).

For example:

Look for Apple (row 2 for first pair, row 5 for second pair)
Subtract the values: 6% - 3.10% = 2.9%

Look for Apples (row 3 for first pair, row 2 for second pair)
Subtract the values: 5% - 2.21% = 2.79%

Look for Mango (row 4 for first pair, row 3 for second pair)
Subtract the values: 2.10% - 8.40% = -6.3%

Look for Orange (row 5 for first pair, row 4 for second pair)
Subtract the values: 3.40% - 9.50% = -6.1%

I tried using Vlookup and sumif but I only get errors. Here's a sample sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1obKG_hp90PyEQ8lJ2Oywi8ctuK0CdAA0Sc5mdNLOyC0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

try this formula:

```
=MAP(A2:A,B2:B,LAMBDA(ax,bx,IF(ax="",,{ax,bx-xlookup(ax,C:C,D:D)})))
```

- 

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({A2:B; C2:C, D2:D*-1}, 
 "select sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"))
```

[image]